# Get particular field or characters from string line in C#

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have one file and read file line by line and extract particular object from string line.

for example string line is in two format.

```
VA001748714600006640126132202STRONG 4P 4X44G000099

VA 00174 871460000664 012 6132202 STRONG 4P 4X44G 000099
```

now i need to extract string and store into my table and fields like below and above two line data generate in below fields(Desire Results).

```
 Code  Location    SerialNo     Quantity  ItemNo      Description      Price
  VA    00174     871460000664     12     6132202    STRONG 4P 4X44G0  000099
```

what i have tried. i have created one method that return `object[]` extract from string

```
public static object[] ProcessLine(string line)
{
        var obj = new object[7];
        var str = line.Replace("\0", "").Replace(" ", "");
        string code = str.Substring(0, 2)?.Trim();
        string location = str.Substring(2, 5)?.Trim();
        string serialNo = str.Substring(7, 12)?.Trim();
        string quantity = str.Substring(19, 3)?.Trim();
        int qty = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(quantity))
        {
            qty = Convert.ToInt32(quantity);
        }
        string itemNo = str.Substring(22, 7)?.Trim();
        Regex MyRegex = new Regex("[^a-z ]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        string description = MyRegex.Replace(line.Substring(2), @"")?.Trim();
        string price = str.Substring(str.Length - 6)?.Trim();
        obj.SetValue(code, 0);
        obj.SetValue(location, 1);
        obj.SetValue(serialNo, 2);
        obj.SetValue(qty, 3);
        obj.SetValue(itemNo, 4);
        obj.SetValue(description, 5);
        obj.SetValue(price, 6);
        return obj;
}
```

i have find sub-string and store into object, also i can't find Description because this field is not fixed letters.

`(Code,Location,SerialNo,Quantity,ItemNo and Price)` are fixed no.of characters and `(Description)` fields are any characters or changes.

how to find this fields value and description using `regex` i tried to find description but it extract without digit.

Comment: Why `Description ` is `STRONG 4P 4X44G0`  and contain spce in the word is there any logic in your `Substring`?

Comment: You may use a regex like [`^(\w{2})\s*(\w{5})\s*(\w{13})\s*(\d{3})\s*(\d{7})\s*(.*?)\s*(\d{6})$`](https://regex101.com/r/uwsnV2/1).

Comment: @DragandDrop by typo mistake i just edit, and yes quantity is 3 char

Comment: Well so Wiktor regex will work, if you replace 13 by 12. You will just have to access the group

Comment: @DragandDrop Yeah, I see it after an edit. I updated the answer to reflect that change.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it works but i have one question i have lots of file and read all file from azure blob trigger and insert record after operation is it any performance changes if we used regex or substring which is better? suggestion :)

Comment: @LaljiDhameliya You are in control of the code, so it is up to you to perform testing. If you use the regex as I have shown (`private static readonly` field, declare the regex with `RegexOptions.Compiled` option), then it will be as fast as LINQ and (in my tests) even faster.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please help me for in as in regex `(\d{3})` how to allow negative number also

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew exa 3 digit like it may be -12 or 012 both possible

Comment: You may use `-?\d{3}` to match an optional `-` and then 3 digits

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not - then 3 digit it is possible total 3 digits including minus but its optional it means 012 and -12 both expression should be matched

Comment: If you want to match such standalone strings, try `^(?=.{1,3}$)-?\d+$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my requirement is not to match such standalone sting but string like i put in question `VA001748714600006640126132202STRONG 4P 4X44G000099` and `012` from string might be possible `-12` etc as in your provided ans how it is possible :)

Comment: Ok,I see now. I think `-?\d{2,3}` should work then. `-` or nothing and then 2 or 3 digits. Or, a bit more specific: `(?:-\d{2}|\d{3})` - hyphen and two digits OR three digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may declare a regex like

```
private static readonly Regex rx = new Regex(@"^(\w{2})\s*(\w{5})\s*(\w{12})\s*(\d{3})\s*(\d{7})\s*(.*?)\s*(\d{6})$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uwsnV2/3).

The point is to use a regex that matches a whole string (`^` match the start of a string and `$` matches the end of the string), use `\w` (any letter/digit/`_` chars) or `\d` (any digit char), `{m}` quantifier to match a certain amount of the chars matched with `\w` or `\d`, match the `Description` field with `.*?`, a lazy dot pattern that matches any 0+ chars other than newline as few as possible, and allow any 0+ whitespace chars in between fields with `\s*`.

Then, you may use it

```
public static object[] ProcessLine(string line)
{
    object[] obj = null;
    var m = rx.Match(line);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        obj = new object[] {
            m.Groups[1].Value,
            m.Groups[2].Value,
            m.Groups[3].Value,
            int.Parse(m.Groups[4].Value).ToString(), // remove leading zeros
            m.Groups[5].Value,
            m.Groups[6].Value,
            m.Groups[7].Value
        };
    }
    return obj;
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/mxZ8pz), demo output for both the strings in OP:

```
VA, 00174, 871460000664, 12, 6132202, KING PEPERM E STRONG 4P 4X44G, 000099
VA, 00174, 871460000664, 12, 6132202, KING PEPERM E STRONG 4P 4X44G, 000099
```

Comment: can you please help me for regex as above it works fine. but after changes require regex for support following breakup.  `VA0002050001125453570246121648SPRITE REFRESH 33CL          00006020190618142214` and `VA0002050001125453570246121648SPRITE REFRESH 33CL          000060` means how to optional last 14 characters in regex `^(\w{2})\s*(\w{5})\s*(\w{13})\s*(\d{3})\s*(\d{7})\s*(.*?)\s*(\d{6})\s*(\d{14})$` here last 14 digit optional

Comment: @LaljiDhameliya Good that you did not post a separate question, it would be a duplicate. See https://regex101.com/r/kqVdq9/1

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use a regex, see [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52144864/20047).

However, you don't need a regex for this problem.

Since all fields except description have known lengths, you can calculate the length of the description field. From your specs the description starts at position 29, and is followed by 6 positions for the price field. Therefore, this should give you the description:

```
string description = str.Substring(29, str.Length-29-6);
```